# Dynamic Ng-Models with Ng-Repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a set of tabs:

```
 <tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab id = "tabContent" ng-repeat="tab in tabs" active="tab.active" ng-model = "cmModel"> <!-- the tab highlight directive -->
      <tab-heading>
      <span>{{tab.title}}</span>
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="removeTab($event, $index)"></i> <!-- the tab close button -->
    </tab-heading>

    <textarea ui-codemirror='cmOption' id="{{ 'Tab ' + ($index+1) }}"  ng-model = "Text"> + "awefwef" + </textarea>

  </tab>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTab()"></button>
</tabset>
```

I'm attempting to set a dynamic ng-model with ng-model = "Text".

First of all, I know that if I really want to add dynamic ng-models, I can't have them all the same (need to somehow add $index to Text). However, the most pressing issue is that $scope.Text is undefined, even though I clearly have added a textarea with ng-model Text.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the end result you trying to have an array of the titles of the various tabs? As with what Qi said, it would be undefined since Text wasn't defined anywhere, so AngularJS wouldn't know how to create a reference to it or any of its properties.

Comment: Sorry, mean to have ng-model = "Text" not ng-model = "Text[tab.title]" in the code section. My current problem is that even though I set ng-model to "Text", $scope.Text is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks if the value of your ng-model can not be find in the tabs, it will get a undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make text a property of each tab? So instead of doing this:

```
<textarea ng-model="Text[tab.title]"></textarea>
```

Do this:

```
<textarea ng-model="tab.text"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Text[Value]
```

That implies you're trying to access a property called "Value" on an object called "Text". If it was just "Text" then angular would create a variable called "Text" on your scope object and all would be well but since you're trying to access a property on the variable before it has actually been created you're getting the reference error.

I'm assuming you have a controller, in which case do:

```
$scope.Text = {}
```

within the controller and what you have should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the issue you're running into is trying to have each tab have their own scope for the tab title. To work with your current setup, you will need to just have the model for the `<textarea>` be set to the `tab.title` itself. This way, it will be tied to that particular tab.

```
<tabset class="tab-container">
    <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-model="cmModel">
        <tab-heading>
            <p>{{tab.title}}</p>
        </tab-heading>
        <br/>
        <textarea id="{{"Tab"+($index+1)}}" ng-model="tab.title"></textarea>
    </tab>
    <p><button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addTab()">Add Tab</button></p>
</tabset>
```

[Working JSFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/13f5m2eb/)